# Error instantiating servlet class [com.example.HelloServlet] caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-migration

i am trying to learn about servlet from a tutorial  I use intellij and this is the structure of the            default project
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cXqh.png)

when i try to send a request to the
`HelloServlet`
i get this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OksI2.png)

this is the structure of the servlet
[HelloServlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xmaI.png)
and this is the pattern of the servlet in **web.xml** file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

the project contain only what I did mention before
and this the URL that I am using to request the servlet

`http://localhost:8080/demo2_war_exploded/home`

also the `init()`
function does not get executed

Comment: See "javax.servlet.* doesn't work anymore in Servlet 5.0 or newer" section of abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: i am not using javax.servlet  i am using jakarta.servlet

Comment: I know. The section contains clues and a link how to correctly use it. It works both ways. javax.servlet doesn't work when you run on server which implements jakarta.servlet or when you blindly put javax.servlet classes in runtime classpath, and from the other side on jakarta.servlet doesn't work when you run on server which implements javax.servlet or when you blindly put jakarta.servlet classes in runtime classpath. See thus the link in that section for an in depth explanation what exactly Tomcat is and how to properly configure pom.xml for it.